# Android: UIdesign

Tags: android

I have problem with `UI` design in `android`. I try to put a button at the  bottom of my `Fragment` and I set it by putting 60dp margin from top elements.

It is in a good position in my `emulator` in IDE , but when I run my project in my phone the button go out of the screen.

emulator device : pixel 2 
my device phone : s8

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context=".sabtHazine" android:layout_weight="1"
             android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">


        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
                android:padding="3dp" android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp">
            <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <EditText
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textPersonName"
                        android:text="Name"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:id="@+id/editText" android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <TextView
                        android:text="مبلغ"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <EditText
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textPersonName"
                        android:text="Name"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:id="@+id/editText" android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <TextView
                        android:text="بابت"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <EditText
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textPersonName"
                        android:text="Name"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:id="@+id/editText2" android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <TextView
                        android:text="تاریخ"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="right" android:layout_marginBottom="150dp">
                <TextView
                        android:text="مشترک با"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
                    <CheckBox
                            android:text="CheckBox"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/checkBox" android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <CheckBox
                            android:text="CheckBox"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/checkBox8" android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <CheckBox
                            android:text="CheckBox"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/checkBox7" android:layout_weight="1"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
                    <CheckBox
                            android:text="CheckBox"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/checkBox8" android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <CheckBox
                            android:text="CheckBox"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/checkBox6" android:layout_weight="1"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <Button
                    android:text="ثبت هزینه"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dp" android:id="@+id/button3" tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="415dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="67dp" android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light" android:background="#1b0387"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:gravity="center" android:layout_marginTop="150dp" android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Share your xml code.

Comment: Better way to put your button relative to your bottom and not to the top elements

Comment: @Tepits i share it now check out

Comment: @Bruno how can i do that

Comment: You can use ConstraintLayout to achieve the same.

Comment: @UmangBurman it works tnx

Comment: just set weight to your **LinearLyaout** to **android:layout_weight="1"** which was creted before **Button**

Answer (score 1):

You should use ConstraintLayout for the best UI design.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="مبلغ" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="بابت" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="تاریخ" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="مشترک با" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="CheckBox" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBox8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="CheckBox" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBox7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="CheckBox" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBox8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="CheckBox" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBox6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="CheckBox" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="#1b0387"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="ثبت هزینه"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you used 60dp margin but its may that this size is good in that resolution and size which your emulator have (xxhdpi) but your phone is difference (xxxhdpi)

make your layout in hdpi xhdpi xxhdpi xxxhdpi sw600dp and sw720dp size

it will help you to make your layout how work good in other phones

or do other thing like using scrollview or other kind of layout

Comment: how can i make my layout in hdpi xhdpi xxhdpi xxxhdpi sw600dp and sw720dp size ??

Comment: @MohammadSeyedmahmudi If you use ConstraintLayout, you don't have to use hdpi xhdpi xxhdpi xxxhdpi sw600dp and sw720dp sizes.

Comment: @ahmadshafizadeh This is not the solution to the problem. Making so many layouts is Time consuming, and doesn't make any sense.

Comment: yes that is correct and i said you can use other layout to solve your problem

Comment: but if he want to do something like that he do now it is better to use this work

Comment: yes your right actually it is better to use ConstraintLayout

Comment: but sometimes your views should get some sizes and you want that your view have especial appearance in all sizes  and appear same in small phone or big tablet in this situation ConstraintLayout may not help

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this help:**

```html
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">
    
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:padding="3dp" android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editText" android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <TextView
                android:text="مبلغ"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editText" android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <TextView
                android:text="بابت"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editText2" android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <TextView
                android:text="تاریخ"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="right" android:layout_marginBottom="150dp">
            <TextView
                android:text="مشترک با"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
                <CheckBox
                    android:text="CheckBox"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/checkBox" android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <CheckBox
                    android:text="CheckBox"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/checkBox8" android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <CheckBox
                    android:text="CheckBox"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/checkBox7" android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
                <CheckBox
                    android:text="CheckBox"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/checkBox8" android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <CheckBox
                    android:text="CheckBox"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/checkBox6" android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        
          
       
    </LinearLayout>
        <Button
            android:text="ثبت هزینه"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:background="#1b0387"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: btn is not at bottom of the screen yet